# Redis BITFIELD atomicity guarantee

Tags: redis

Is following operation atomic? Cause redis calls it subcommands

```
BITFIELD key1 GET u8 0 INCRBY u8 0 10 OVERFLOW WRAP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is atomic. Every data-path command in Redis is atomic.

A sub-command in Redis simply means a command with an additional 'operation' parameter (e.g., `BITFIELD` key - where the subcommand can be `GET`, `SET`, or `INCRBY` or `CONFIG` with `GET`, `HELP`, `RESETSTAT`,`REWRITE` and `SET`).

Specifically for `BITFIELD`, a single command can process multiple operations (each specified by a sub-command). All these operations are processed sequentially, and the whole command is atomic.

Comment: Hmm i knew that but for some commands they had explicitly highlighted atomicity like setget in prev docs so was wondering if they mentioned this somewhere in docs...